# Create POT file with Poedit

Tags: php, poedit

I'm trying desperately to create a catalog (. In) for my new application in php.
1) I created a file "trans.php" where I put all the values ​​to be translated

For example, here is my file:

```
<?php 

echo _e('SORTIR LA NUIT');

?>
```

2) I open Poedit, in the "Paths" here's what I entered (see photo)
Then I save the same location of my file "php".

[image: paths configuration in Poedit]

3) When I click "update", I have the following errors:

```
12:25:43: No files found in: /Users/aweaoftheworld/Desktop/test
12:25:43: Poedit did not find any files in scanned directories.
12:25:43: Entries in the catalog are probably incorrect.
12:25:43: Updating the catalog failed. Click on 'More>>' for details.
```

Can you help me?

Sincerely,

Comment: `_()` is an alias for `gettext()` http://php.net/manual/function.gettext.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should use **_** instead of **_e**, for example

```
<?php echo _("hi there i am gettext library") ?>
```

by the way, **_e** function is from Wordpress engine, it doing same but it's not PHP predefined function.

Answer (score 17):

Make sure the path(s) defined in POEdit (`Catalog > Settings > Paths`) point to the folder that contains your PHP files. This should solve the problem of POEdit not finding the files.

If the `did not find any files in scanned directories` is resolved, POEdit will probably still find 0 messages. This is because by default POEdit doesn't support `_e` as a keyword. To resolve this problem, simply add "`_e`" to the list of keywords (in `Catalog > Settings > Keywords`).

Comment: I was using _() and the Paths were correct, but POEdit 1.4.6 could not parse anything (same error), while manually using xgettext worked fine. In my case upgrading to 1.5.4 solved the problem (OS: Ubuntu 12.04.4).

Answer (score 1):

Only if i use _() instead of _e() or instead of __() - poedit can find my strings - but, in wordpress i get this error:

Warning: _() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx.php on line xxx

it was after i try to add this: __() and this: _e() to "Keywords" but its did'nt solve the problem...
so for me the solution is to change it to _() for po edit and after it take all the words from code(wp theme or plugin) i change it all to __().

Comment: That's just silly. See the answer right above yours for what you're doing wrong -- you need to add this *non-default* keyword.

Comment: in line 4 i wrote:
it was after i try to add this: __() and this: _e() to "Keywords" but its did'nt solve the problem...

Comment: Then you either use _e() incorrectly in your code or didn't in fact add it to Keywords by some accident (perhaps misspelling it) or didn't refresh the catalog. But the fact is that the non-default _e keyword is recognized perfectly fine by Poedit and xgettext and whatever problem you're having, it's not with Poedit's inability to see _e().